# Set multple primary keys with mixed syntax

Tags: python, sqlite

I am currently struggling with multiple primary keys with a forced mixed syntax.
The script i am writing is supposed to duplicate a remote database but i need to add another primary key to the table.

The new key must be a "INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT"-Key.

The "CREATE TABLE"-Statement from the remote database looks currently like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "Table_1" (id text, ord text, mod_date TEXT, val TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (id,ord));
```

What i tried and failed with is following modification:

```
CREATE TABLE "Table_1" (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, id text, ord text, mod_date TEXT, val TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (id,ord));
```

Is there a way to achieve this or do i have to write a function to unzip the "PRIMARY KEY(...)"-Part to be able to set the "PRIMARY KEY"-Statement for each primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have 2 primary keys in a table.
You have defined the primary key as `PRIMARY KEY (id,ord)`.

But SQLite does provide what you need because all tables that are not created with `WITHOUT ROWID` are [`Rowid tables`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html).
So you already have an auto increment column in your table named `rowid` and you can use it although it is not defined in the `CREATE` statement of the table.
This is actually:

> The true primary key for a rowid table (the value that is used as the
> key to look up rows in the underlying B-tree storage engine)